# Windows 7 or Windows 2008 how to launch a process in Local System Account or System Context (from desktop aplication)

Tags: c++, windows-7, createprocess, local-system-account

In C++ I want to launch a process from my Desktop Application in "Local System account" or "System Context". My application executes with admin privileges.

Is it possible?
How?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what [SysRun](http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~bfriesen/software/sysrun.shtml) does: install a system service and launch the app from the service.

Comment: Thanks for replying but I want to write C++ code for it. I don't want to use third party executable.

Comment: You can write your own implementation of the service.

Comment: In your suggestion I need to create a temp service and write code inside the service. My concern is whether it's a standard practice or a work around.

Comment: Launching a process as LocalSystem in general is not standard practice.